# intent-filter build two apps instead of one in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, react-native, main-activity

I have a react native Project that's integrated with onesignal notification, in Android app when I built my app using Android Studio it installs two apps one called onesignal and the other one my main app and app runs perfect

I tried to remove the intent from my activity

```
       <activity android:name="bkholdnews.beonews.MainActivity" android:label="OneSignal Example" android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and rebuilt the app, it installs one app but when I open it it says app keeps stooping!

my MainActivity code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hhz20.bkholdnews"
    android:versionCode="29"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> <!-- Approximate location - If you want to use promptLocation for letting OneSignal know the user location. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> <!--  Precise location If you want to use promptLocation for letting OneSignal know the user location. -->

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:name="bkholdnews.beonews.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name="bkholdnews.beonews.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="bkholdnews.beonews.MainActivity" android:label="OneSignal Example" android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

CRASH LOGCAT

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2019-06-01 17:31:18.598 30803-30803/com.hhz20.bkholdnews E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hhz20.bkholdnews, PID: 30803
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hhz20.bkholdnews/bkholdnews.beonews.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.hhz20.bkholdnews:drawable/splash_screen with resource ID #0x7f0700b1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.hhz20.bkholdnews:drawable/splash_screen with resource ID #0x7f0700b1
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_screen.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700b1
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:847)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:631)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:888)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:827)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:626)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:260)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
        at bkholdnews.beonews.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:9)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:849)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:770)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
2019-06-01 17:31:18.599 30803-30803/com.hhz20.bkholdnews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1321)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:279)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:194)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1291)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:833)
            ... 27 more
2019-06-01 17:31:18.612 30803-30803/com.hhz20.bkholdnews I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30803 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have to remove intent filter from main  activity in the manifest file and  start activity transaction through splash screen to main activity and also remove launchmode from mainactivity

Comment: I removed this whole code,         <activity android:name="bkholdnews.beonews.MainActivity" android:label="OneSignal Example" android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>    and the app gives me app keep stopping error when when I launch it

Comment: show your logcat status while you are getting error

Comment: did you got the sollution ? as i informed